# How do I enhance the '~' command to toggle the "+/-" signs as well?

Tags: vimscript, key-bindings

I need to make a report about investment everyday. It requires a lot of changes of the sign of figures. (from `-` to `+` or from `+` to `-`)

Is there a simple way to overload (extend) the `~` command (switch case) with such a toggle function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do:

```
function! ExtendToggle()
  let char = getline(line('.'))[col('.')-1]
  if char == '-'
    return 'r+l'
  elseif char == '+'
    return 'r-l'
  else
    return '~'
  endif
endfunction

nnoremap <expr> ~ ExtendToggle()
```

Comment: Great! That's just what I need/want! Thank you very much!

I append a SPACE to 'r+' and 'r-' so that it advances afterward like what '~' would do.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll adapt the solution according to your remark (replacing `<space> ` by `l` since for a number of us `<space>` is the leader key)

Comment: Note that using `<space>` should be OK because it is protected by `nnoremap`. The space will just be a space, not a leader or any other mapping.

Comment: You are right. The `<leader>` are only used in mapping and the `nnoremap` is ignoring the mapping so indeed it should be fine (to be sure I have tested) :-)